# c++ delete [] always hangs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, delete-operator

I have implemented my own simple vector, all functions seems fine except on `alloc_new()`, when it tries to create new memory and copy the contents their and delete the old memory allocation.
My programs always hangs and never execute after that.

```
                class myvector{
            private:
                int vsize, maxsize;
                int* arr;
                void alloc_new();
            public:
                myvector();
                myvector(int);
                myvector(const myvector&);
                ~myvector();

                void push_back(int);
                int size();
                int operator[](int);
                int at(int);
                void display();
            };

            myvector::myvector(){
                maxsize = 20;
                vsize = 0;
                arr = new int[maxsize];
            }

            void myvector::alloc_new(){
                // Allocate new space, double of current size
                maxsize = maxsize*2;
                int* arr_new = new int[maxsize];
                //copy the elements from the base location to new location
                for(int i=0; i < vsize ; i++)
                    arr_new[i] = arr[i];
                delete[] arr;  // MY PROGRAM ALWAYS HANGS HERE
                arr = arr_new;
            }

            void myvector::push_back(int val){
                if((vsize+1) > maxsize)
                    alloc_new();
                arr[++vsize] = val;
            }

            int main(){
                myvector vect;
                for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
                    vect.push_back(rand()%100+1);
                }
                getch();
            }
```

Comment: This is usually a sign that you have corrupted the heap - try running under valgrind.

Comment: Experiments indicate that this happens with Visual C++ when `maxsize` is originally 20 – but not e.g. 19 or 21. I suspect it has something to do with the block size of the underlying OS allocator, and that it's a compiler bug. You can report it at the "Microsoft connect" site.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Bug in push_back goes over the edge. Presumably this then also needs to coincide with allocation being "even size", or you just overwrite the spare space in the allocation (on my linux system, it runs perfectly fine, but valgrind finds the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your "have we reached max size" is wrong. You are comparing `vsize + 1 > maxsize`. This means that you are writing to `arr[++vsize]` when `vsize + 1 == maxsize`. This writes one element PAST your allocation [in other words, index 20 were 0..19 are valid indices], and thus goes wrong.

Fix the code like this:

```
void myvector::push_back(int val){
    if((vsize+1) >= maxsize)
    alloc_new();
    arr[++vsize] = val;
}
```

Using valgrind will tell you:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==20918== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20918== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20918== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20918== Command: ./a.out
==20918== 
==20918== Invalid write of size 4
==20918==    at 0x4009E9: myvector::push_back(int) (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==20918==    by 0x400AA1: main (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==20918==  Address 0x5a20090 is 0 bytes after a block of size 80 alloc'd
==20918==    at 0x4C2A77C: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20918==    by 0x4008B4: myvector::myvector() (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==20918==    by 0x400A57: main (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==20918== 
==20918== 
==20918== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20918==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20918==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 240 bytes allocated
==20918== 
==20918== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20918== 
==20918== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20918== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: **➕1** well spotted! [[[[[[[[[[[[

Comment: Actually, I ran valgrind... ;)

Comment: Thanks Mats Petersson, i changed the push_back boundary check....and it worked for me. Also noted the Valgrind tool for future reference...!!!! :)